# Why am I getting .scss classes when downing Bootstrap 5 via the jsdeliver CDN

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-5

I have been using my Mac Book Pro to build my application with Bootstrap 5. Everything works fine. I cloned my application to my Ubuntu/Apache server and now Chrome dev tools says the Bootstrap 5 classes are coming out as .scss not .css as on my Mac Book. The result is that my app does not render properly. The crazy thing is that I can tell Bootstrap is touching some of my application as the fonts are BS fonts. But all the tables and containers do not work. I use Laravel/ui which comes bundled with BS. However that is not used in the main body of the app only on the login pages. so I use the the Bootstrap CDN, jsdeliver on both machines, for the body of the app.  I have Bootstrap.js loaded. I have worked on this for ages and can't figure it out. The file permissions are good. The user is www-data. All the while my Mac Book works fine. Note: both platforms use Laravel 10. However the Mac Book uses Laravel Valet not Apache.

Comment: If you are using a CDN to include the .css and .js distribution files of bootstrap then what you are seeing in chrome dev tools may be source maps instead of what is actually loaded. It is hard to tell what is actually happening as there is no additional information shared here. Worth checking the "sources" tab in chrome dev tools for the CDN to see if the file is downloaded from that as it's requested.

Comment: thanks for that. Yes, it is coming from jsdeliver. I selected one of the .scss classes and found that it comes from something called " Bootstrap reboot'. I don't know what that is about. Checking into it. Why can't just have nice .css.